# EOL in Notepad++ and Notepad

Tags: notepad++, file-format

I'm using Notepad++ to create some text file, but I noticed when the generated file is opened in Windows Notepad, the file contents get mal-formated due to the fact that Notepad++ use LF and EOL character, while Notepad expects CR + LF.

Is there any way to change this behavior in Notepad++??

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I guess you're looking for the Notepad++ menu entry "Edit -> EOL Conversion". You can convert to Windows/Linux/Mac EOL there. The current format is displayed in the status bar.

[image: Notepad++ menu - Edit - EOL Conversion - Windows (CR LF)]

Comment: Already checked all menus...I can't find EOL Conversion anywhere...which version are you using? I'll accept the answer, probably I'm using an older version of the product.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Version 5.7.  In that version, you can go to Edit -> EOL Conversion and change the format of the end of line character between MAC, Windows and Unix.

Comment: Why did you post almost the same answer as the accepted one some months later?